# translating vanilla JavaScript to React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, magenta

im trying to understand how we can translate a very simple javascript program into ReactJS. My limited front end experience is with React, where things are wrapped in components or functions to render output.

This simple program has 3 components, which i would like to place into a React class or function:

1, a JavaScript object for note pitches.

```
TWINKLE_TWINKLE = {
  notes: [
    {pitch: 60, startTime: 0.0, endTime: 0.5},
    {pitch: 60, startTime: 0.5, endTime: 1.0},
    ... 
  ],
  totalTime: 5
};
```

2, the import, which can output notes:

```
player = new mm.Player();
```

3, the runner, which should output them.

```
player.start(TWINKLE_TWINKLE);
player.stop();
```

I would like to wrap this in a react class that i could then export. I know this may be a very simple question, but it would be very helpful to understand.

Comment: Have a look at my edit - on `Chrome` it won't start playing unless there's some use action, i.e. clicking on a button the way I have it in my edit. I've tested it with a `create-react-app` setup and it works. That `componentDidMount` lifecycle wouldn't work as user action is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instal the proper dependency:

```
npm install @magenta/music
```

Then, inside your `React` code, do the following:

```js
import React from "react";
import * as mm from "@magenta/music/es6";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.TWINKLE_TWINKLE = {
      notes: [
        { pitch: 60, startTime: 0.0, endTime: 0.5 },
        { pitch: 60, startTime: 0.5, endTime: 1.0 },
        { pitch: 67, startTime: 1.0, endTime: 1.5 },
        { pitch: 67, startTime: 1.5, endTime: 2.0 },
        { pitch: 69, startTime: 2.0, endTime: 2.5 },
        { pitch: 69, startTime: 2.5, endTime: 3.0 },
        { pitch: 67, startTime: 3.0, endTime: 4.0 },
        { pitch: 65, startTime: 4.0, endTime: 4.5 },
        { pitch: 65, startTime: 4.5, endTime: 5.0 },
        { pitch: 64, startTime: 5.0, endTime: 5.5 },
        { pitch: 64, startTime: 5.5, endTime: 6.0 },
        { pitch: 62, startTime: 6.0, endTime: 6.5 },
        { pitch: 62, startTime: 6.5, endTime: 7.0 },
        { pitch: 60, startTime: 7.0, endTime: 8.0 },
      ],
      totalTime: 8,
    };
    this.player = new mm.Player();
  }

  play = () => {
    if (this.player.isPlaying()) {
      return;
    }
    this.player.start(this.TWINKLE_TWINKLE);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.play}>
          Play!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```